# Question about solution to exponential equation.

Tags: proof-verification, exponential-function

I was given this problem in class:

$\frac{100}{e^{-2x}}=50$

I attempted to to solve it:

$100=50(e^{-2x})$

$e^{-2x}=2$

$\ln e^{-2x}= \ln2$

$-2x=\ln 2$

$x=-\frac {\ln2}{2}$

Would this be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct! Well done!

Ultimately, you can rewrite this answer as $x = -ln(\sqrt{2})$ or $x = ln(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$

Comment: Could you show me how I could get from $-\frac{\ln2}{2}$ to $-\ln(\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: Use the property: $a*ln(b) = ln(b^a)$